# Como criar uma caixa com linhas dos dois lados só com CSS

Tags: html, css

Estou querendo uma ajuda de por onde começar para conseguir criar uma estrutura totalmente em css como na imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sei que isso pode parecer muito simples, mais não to conseguindo começar.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Na verdade nem é tão óbvio assim. Quase tudo no CSS é baseado em caixas, e o que você precisa é uma caixa e duas linhas. Tem várias maneiras de conseguir isso, e vou mostrar um caminho usando 2 elementos: um container, e um box dentro com o nome do mês:

```
<div class="divisor">
  <div class="mes">outubro</div>
</div>
```

O container tem o mínimo de CSS, somente para permitir que posicionemos com precisão o que temos dentro dele:

```
.divisor {
    position: relative;
}
```

O CSS do box com o nome do mês define uma caixa centralizada, cinza, com borda branca grossa. A borda é um truque para cobrir parte da linha que iremos colocar atrás do box, fazendo parecer que são duas linhas, uma de cada lado.

```
.divisor .mes {
    width: 100px;
    background: #cccccc; /* cinza */
    border: 10px solid #ffffff; /* borda branca em volta */
    margin: 0 auto; /* centraliza com bordas automáticas nas laterais */
    text-align: center; /* centraliza o texto */
    padding: 12px 24px; /* respiro em volta do texto */
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #666666; /* texto cinza escuro */ 
    z-index: 2; /* na frente da linha */
    position: relative; /* exigido pelo z-index */
}
```

A linha será um elemento gerado pelo próprio CSS, para não poluir nosso HTML. É um *pseudo-elemento*, que neste caso geraremos com o seletor `:before`, que irá criar um novo elemento "fantasma" dentro do container, antes do box com o nome do mês:

```
.divisor:before {
    position: absolute; /* posição relativa ao container */
    top: 50%; /* posição vetical: bem na metade */
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #666666;
    z-index: 1; /* atrás do box do mês */
}
```

Agora tudo junto e funcionando:

```css
.divisor {
    position: relative;
}
.divisor .mes {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    background: #cccccc; /* cinza */
    border: 10px solid #ffffff; /* borda branca em volta */
    margin: 0 auto; /* centraliza com bordas automáticas nas laterais */
    text-align: center; /* centraliza o texto */
    padding: 12px 24px; /* respiro em volta do texto */
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #666666; /* texto cinza escuro */ 
    z-index: 2; /* na frente da linha */
}

.divisor:before {
    position: absolute; /* posição relativa ao container */
    top: 50%; /* posição vetical: bem na metade */
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #666666;
    z-index: 1; /* atrás do box do mês */
}
```

```html
<div class="divisor">
  <div class="mes">outubro</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Chique... perfeito rapaz, deu pra entender a lógica, muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 7):

Adoro esses exercícios, reforçam bastante a criatividade :P
Na minha solução, eu usei dois elementos: a linha e o conteúdo (que seria onde está escrito o mês). Dessa forma:

```
<div class="line_row"><div class="content">outubro</div></div>
```

Primeiro vamos fazer a linha (ignore o texto). Como na imagem, coloquei a altura para 1px e largura por volta dos 90%. Para que o texto ficasse centralizado verticalmente, defini a `line-height` para 1px (altura da linha). Ai depois coloquei uma margem para a linha ficar centraliza e dar um espaço pra cima, por fim defini o `text-align` para `center` para o texto ficar centralizado.

Para o texto, coloquei o background para `#ccc` para combinar com a linha e um `padding` para o texto não ficar colado. Você irá perceber que o background pega toda a linha, isso porque a div `.content` não tem uma largura definida. Isso é resolvido definindo `display:inline;`. E por fim, adicionei uma borda branca, para simular a quebra das linhas.

Qualquer dúvida pergunte, estamos aqui para ajudar. Exemplo completo:

```css
.line_row {
    margin:25px auto;
    width:90%;
    height:1px;
    background-color:#ccc;
    line-height:1px;
    text-align:center;
}

.content {
    padding:7px 15px;
    background-color:#ccc;
    display:inline;
    color:#333;
    border:10px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="line_row">
  <div class="content">outubro</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Chique, eu sinceramente não ia conseguir fazer kkkkk, mais deu uma clareada grande e deu pra entender bem como fazer, muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 4):

Fiz uma exemplo de uma forma diferente do @bfavaretto (que no fim é praticamente o mesmo resultado), acompanhe minha solução (tentei explicar o que foi feito nos comentários ao lado das propriedades CSS):

```css
div.traco {
  height: 13px;  /* Altura da linha (metade a altura do div.title)*/
  border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD;  /* borda de 1px cinza, para dar o efeito de traço */
  text-align: center;  /* Para centralizar de forma simples o conteúdo (div.title) ao centro */
}
div.traco > div.title {
  padding: 5px;  /* espaçameento ao redor do testo do titulo para criar o box */
  background-color: #DDDDDD;  /* cor de fundo do titulo (div.title) - cinza */
  display: inline-block;  /* para que o tamanho horizontal do titulo (div.title) seja de acordo com o tamanho de seu conteúdo */
  border-color: #ffffff;  /* cor branca da borda para dar o efeito de que o traço tem um espaçamento do titulo */
  border-style: solid;  /* stilo da borda */
  border-width: 0 10px;  /* seta os tamanhos da borda (para dar o efeito de que o traço tem um espaçamento do titulo), 0px em cima e em baixo (pois não é necessirio borda) e 10px na direita e na esquerda */
}
```

```html
<div class="traco">
  <div class="title">Outubro</div>
</div>
```

[Aqui uma exemplo utilizando esse Title em varias `sections`](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/xs12vsjh/2/)

Comment: Gostei da sua solução e da do Rafael, pois se aproveitam do overflow (a div de dentro vaza, é maior que a de fora). Eu não pensei nisso, parti do princípio de que o container precisaria conter tudo. Vocês dois economizaram um elemento.

Comment: @bfavaretto, mas analisando melhor, sua solução é muito melhor que a nossa, por exemplo, inspecione o elemento do titulo/mês e altere a fonte para maior. Na minha solução e na do Rafael, você verá que o traço já não vai acompanhar ficando fora do centro vertical, já em sua solução o traço está diretamente ligado ao tamanho do titulo/mês, sendo assim sua solução se torna muito mais dinâmica e adaptável.  =D

Comment: Obrigado Fernando, mais uma idéia de como fazer, chique cara e muito obrigado pela ajuda.