# Sobrepor div sobre before, css

Tags: css

Como sobrepor o conteúdo da div sobre o elemento before dela mesma?
Estou teentando fazer com que a linha reta nao apareça quando estivar nas palavras, pra ficar tipo assim:

> --------- dsdsdsds --------

```css
.abc {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #C1BEBE;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 23px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
}
.abc::before {
    content: '';
    border-bottom: 1px solid #C2BFBF;
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: -43px;
    position: relative;
    top: 9px;
    z-index: -13333;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:300px">
  <div class="abc">ab c mdo emosd sd</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sua pergunta foi restaurada pois tinha uma resposta. Lembre-se de que o conteúdo que você posta aqui passa a pertencer à comunidade, e que as respostas podem ser úteis para outras pessoas, elas não são só para você. Portanto, excluir uma pergunta respondida é desrespeitar quem respondeu, tentando ajudar tanto a você, quanto à comunidade como um todo.

Comment: @bfavaretto Oh, não fiz por maldade, caso tenha visto funcionou na resposta dele e não em meu problema original o que me leva a crer que é um problema maior e isolado com meu script, por isso eu iria apagar e refazer a pergunta só que pegando problemas maiores como ele mesmo pediu nos comentários da resposta dele, achei melhor apagar por que a razão do erro era maior e não tinha a ver com esta pergunta.

Comment: Por sinal @Sergio é muito bom no que faz, sempre me dá respostas diretas e que resolvem o problema, não fiz com intenção de desrespeitar ninguém, mas caso ache válido deixar uma pergunta sem foco e nexo que não irá ajudar em nada online problema não é meu.. Não irei ser eu que ficarei confuso futuramente. Acho que não se deve olhar pro problema por cima, deve-se analisar a pergunta/resposta e ver se realmente é util mante-la em casos como este. Fica a critério de algumas pessoas.

Comment: Eu concordo que cada pergunta deve ser julgada individualmente. Mas entendo que esta, da maneira como está escrita, fica respondida pelo que o Sergio disse. Não posso falar sobre o seu problema original, que parece depender do contexto que não faz parte do que você postou. Então acho que vale a pena manter sim.

Comment: @bfavaretto Tudo bem.. Fica a seu critério, assim que eu entender meu problema eu reposto uma nova pergunta.. obrigado!

Comment: Certo. Não sei se entendi seu objetivo final, mas talvez isto ajude: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58703/como-criar-uma-caixa-com-linhas-dos-dois-lados-s%C3%B3-com-css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se retirares o `z-index` do elemento que terá depois o `::before` já vai funcionar como queres.

```
.abc {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #C1BEBE;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 23px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    position: relative;
/*    z-index: 999; <---retirei */
}
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d1n2ns7o/2/

Comment: no meu script final nao funciona de forma alguma, será que voce tem uma alternativa para o que eu quero?

Comment: @user3163662 o meu jsFiddle funciona como queres certo? se não funciona no teu script preciso de ver o teu script. Adapta o meu jsFiddle até reproduzires o problema.